# Sqlite error on foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create the relations between 3 tables through a foreign key. Something is wrong because pop a complitation error.

```
SQLiteException: near "code_element" which is equal to KEY_ELEMENTCODE in DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS
```

The code is as follows:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLESTUDY + " (" +
                KEY_ROWSTUDYID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_STUDYCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_STUDYNAME + " TEXT " +
                KEY_STUDANALYST + " TEXT " +
                KEY_STUDYPHOTO + " BLOB);"          
        );          
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " (" +
                KEY_ROWELEMENTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_STUDYID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_STUDYID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLESTUDY+" ("+KEY_ROWSTUDYID+"), " +
                KEY_ELEMENTCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT " +
                KEY_ELEMENTPHOTO + " BLOB);"            
        );          
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEDATA + " (" +
                KEY_ROWDATATID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_ELEMENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ELEMENTID+") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " ("+KEY_ROWELEMENTID+"), " +
                KEY_DATEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TIMEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ACTIVITYDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOURDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, );"         
        );
```

Comment: can you post the LogCat error

Answer (score 0):

All your 3 Create Table statements are wrong:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLESTUDY + " (" +
            KEY_ROWSTUDYID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_STUDYCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_STUDYNAME + " TEXT " +   // Missing comma!
            KEY_STUDANALYST + " TEXT " + // Missing comma!
            KEY_STUDYPHOTO + " BLOB);"
    );
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " (" +
            KEY_ROWELEMENTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_STUDYID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_STUDYID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLESTUDY+" ("+KEY_ROWSTUDYID+"), " +
            KEY_ELEMENTCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT " + // Missing comma!
            KEY_ELEMENTPHOTO + " BLOB);"
    );
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEDATA + " (" +
            KEY_ROWDATATID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ELEMENTID+") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " ("+KEY_ROWELEMENTID+"), " +
            KEY_DATEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_TIMEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ACTIVITYDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_HOURDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, );" // Extra comma!
    );
```

They should be:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLESTUDY + " (" +
            KEY_ROWSTUDYID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_STUDYCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_STUDYNAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_STUDANALYST + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_STUDYPHOTO + " BLOB);"
    );
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " (" +
            KEY_ROWELEMENTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_STUDYID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_STUDYID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLESTUDY+" ("+KEY_ROWSTUDYID+"), " +
            KEY_ELEMENTCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTPHOTO + " BLOB);"
    );
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEDATA + " (" +
            KEY_ROWDATATID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ELEMENTID+") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " ("+KEY_ROWELEMENTID+"), " +
            KEY_DATEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_TIMEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ACTIVITYDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_HOURDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
    );
```

**[EDIT]**

I updated my answer to reflect your latest changes:

Two of your Create Table statements are STILL WRONG (extra commas at the end):

```
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " (" +
            KEY_ROWELEMENTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_STUDYID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_STUDYID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLESTUDY+" ("+KEY_ROWSTUDYID+"), " +
            KEY_ELEMENTCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTPHOTO + " BLOB, );"       // Extra comma!
    );          
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEDATA + " (" +
            KEY_ROWDATATID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ELEMENTID+") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " ("+KEY_ROWELEMENTID+"), " +
            KEY_DATEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_TIMEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ACTIVITYDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_HOURDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, );"  // Extra comma!
    );
```

They should be:

```
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " (" +
            KEY_ROWELEMENTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_STUDYID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_STUDYID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLESTUDY+" ("+KEY_ROWSTUDYID+"), " +
            KEY_ELEMENTCODE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTPHOTO + " BLOB );"          
    );          
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEDATA + " (" +
            KEY_ROWDATATID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_ELEMENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ELEMENTID+") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " ("+KEY_ROWELEMENTID+"), " +
            KEY_DATEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_TIMEDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ACTIVITYDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_HOURDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL );"         
    );
```

Comment: But these missing/wrong commas did not cause the error in the question. The same syntax error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

In

> KEY_STUDYNAME + " TEXT " +
>                   KEY_STUDANALYST + " TEXT " +

and

```
 KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT " +
```

**','**

after  TEXT missed.

And requests

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DATABASE_TABLESTUDY  (
                KEY_ROWSTUDYID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                KEY_STUDYCODE  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
                KEY_STUDYNAME  TEXT,
                KEY_STUDANALYST  TEXT,
                KEY_STUDYPHOTO  BLOB);"
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS (
                    KEY_ROWELEMENTID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                    KEY_STUDYID  TEXT NOT NULL,
                    KEY_ELEMENTCODE TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
                    KEY_ELEMENTNAME  TEXT ,
                    KEY_ELEMENTPHOTO BLOB,  FOREIGN KEY (KEY_STUDYID) REFERENCES  DATABASE_TABLESTUDY ( KEY_ROWSTUDYID ));"
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  DATABASE_TABLEDATA (
                    KEY_ROWDATATID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    KEY_ELEMENTID  TEXT NOT NULL,  
                    KEY_DATEDATA TEXT NOT NULL,
                    KEY_TIMEDATA  TEXT NOT NULL,
                    KEY_ACTIVITYDATA  TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    KEY_HOURDATA  TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (KEY_ELEMENTID) REFERENCES   DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS  (KEY_ROWELEMENTID) )"
```

are successful. Please try, just change static strings to your variables.

Comment: Also **KEY_HOURDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, );"** has an EXTRA "," that should be removed.